# Set unrequired parameter in url in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes

How to set one action to multiply URLs in Symfony2.8 (annotation type)?
I need something like this:
/credit/{credit-type}
where "credit-type" parameter may be empty:
/credit/
I used this:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{credit}/{credit-type}/", name="credit_page_single", defaults={"credit-type" = "null"})
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @param $credit
     * @param $credit-type
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
```

Same thing in Laravel you can get when put the '?' symbol after the parameter that could be empty: `/credit/{credit-type?}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set multiple routes to you action, like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{credit}/{credit-type}/", name="credit_page_single", defaults={"credit-type" = "null"})
 * @Route("/{credit}/", name="credit_page_single_without_parameter")
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 * @param $credit
 * @param $credit-type
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
```

Comment: Should I place $credit-type = null in my action parameters?

Comment: in this case yes